# how to setup rule events for before/after video is played?

Tags: rules, files

How can I set up a rule events for actions to occur before and after videos are played in a node?

Thank you for any tips/ help you can give!

Comment: How is your video being embedded in the page? How do you propose to detect when it is started/ended ? You can trigger a rule via ajax. You have not included even close to enough information for someone to help you.

Comment: Thank you 2pha for your reply, much appreciated. I am new here and learning, so am doing my best - apologies if I haven't given enough information. The videos are a field in a node. Exactly, I am unsure how I can set up a rule for this, to detect/ trigger an action when a video is started (played) and ended. I know how to set up the rules, I see there is 'content is viewed' and can set up the type as that node but that is not specific enough about a video being played. So how to set up this rule is confounding me. Any ideas?

Comment: first figure out how your video is being embedded and how to fire the javascript events.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm using the Video module. Not sure of how to fire the javascript events, but this is a good guidance to try to start working it out. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When video start/end it should call js function which trigger ajax call for path you create on drupal (using hook_menu) the callback of that menu item should call the rule you want using rules invoke function 
    rules_invoke_component('rule_name', $arg);

So the case is how to trigger the ajax call on start/end

if you are using youtube, check this page, you can trigger js function to start the ajax

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

if you have another player you should look to the api

Comment: Might want to implement some sort of flood control on the callback.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/project/mediafront_popcornplayer allows you to configure events that are triggered when a video's playback reaches a specific point in time.  This is similar to how the YouTube API works, but abstracted so that it works with any video provider with a Popcorn.js wrapper.  That currently includes YouTube, Vimeo, Archive.org and Solidtango.  https://www.drupal.org/project/mediafront provides the UI and logic for a site builder to use the Popcorn Player on any Media field on the content type or just in a specific View.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2434915

Once the Popcorn Player is being used to load the video, the point that the user is at in the timeline is available to you.  While there isn't anything specific to integrate this with Rules, you can really do anything you want to alter objects in the DOM like http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-with-youtube.  It would be really easy to implement a call back to something like https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_link with Popcorn.

Comment: Kreynan that is so very helpful - very very much appreciated!

Comment: While that gives you a structure to work with, the Popcorn Player is very much under active development.  Feel free to open issues in that project's queue and I'll try to incorporate your needs into the next release.

You can see an example of Popcorn Player running with chapter deeplinking into the video and speakers details as footnotes at http://okv.se/play/region-kronoberg/150225.  

Also when someone gives you an answer that is helpful, it is common practice to vote that answer up and/or mark it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks Kreynen. I tried to vote up your answer however as I am new here it does not give me permission. This is very helpful to what I'm doing as yes I would like to trigger actions mid-video. I am particularly interested to trigger a series of choices for what videos can next be played- I will see if that feature/functionality can be done in popcorn (I presume so, from the goals of the project). The initial question was about how to trigger actions before and after video playback (i.e. on cueing the video, and stopping the video)- I am not sure if the popcorn player can do that part of it?